# Qt $$[...] - configuration option that were set when Qt was built

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm looking at this Qt5 .pro file. It has the following entry:

```
DESTDIR = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/ms_plugins
```

I know that this means the compiled module's output (a plugin) should go into the `ms_plugins` subfolder in the Qt5 plugins install location. I have verified that the plugin does indeed go into that location.

My questions are:

1. Where is `QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS` defined?
2. On a related note, is there a similar variable that holds the
   location of the build directory. Typically, something like
   `build_Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_clang_64bit-Debug` on my Mac.
3. Any documentation of all available variables?

EDIT: I've found some description of these variables [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables), although, I still don't see where they're defined.

EDIT2: Mostly for future visitors. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables) mentions `The special $$[...] operator can be used to access various configuration options that were set when Qt was built:`. So in order to figure out what `QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS` is we can put the following in a .pro file:

```
message(Plugins: $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS is one of the built-in properties of qmake. The [manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html) of qmake in Qt 4.8 talks about qmake's built-in properties but does not mention QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS specifically. The [manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-environment-reference.html) of qmake in Qt 5 shows a much longer list of built-in properties including QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS. If you take a look at the [source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/6d76e943dab0971d376cebb15fe531efc60622ac%3aqmake/property.cpp) of qmake you can see that the value of a built-in property is determined by calling QLibraryInfo::location() ([source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/6d76e943dab0971d376cebb15fe531efc60622ac%3asrc/corelib/global/qlibraryinfo.cpp), [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlibraryinfo.html#location)).
2. The location of the build directory can be found in a variable called [OUT_PWD](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#out-pwd): OUT_PWD `specifies the full path leading to the directory where qmake places the generated Makefile`.
3. You can find the documentation of all available variables [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

`QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS` is a persistent property of `qmake`. You can print its value on the command line using

```
qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS
```

To change this location, use `qmake -set <property> <value>`. Type `qmake -help` for more information.